# SQL - Complex Delete with Multiple Linking Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, business-logic

I have a SQL delete that I need to construct, that makes use of a complex data structure that includes 6 tables:

- Users (UserID, etc)
- Catalogs (CatalogID, etc)
- Libraries (LibraryID, etc)
- User_Catalogs (UserID, CatalogID)
- User_Libraries (UserID, LibraryID)
- Catalog_Libraries (CatalogID, LibraryID)

In order to make sense of this, the business logic is as follows:

- A user is assigned a catalog (User_Catalogs); this assigns all the libraries in that catalog (Catalog_Libraries) to the user (User_Libraries)
- The user can then remove the libraries they don't want from their view (hense the separate linking table, User_Libraries)

The problem I need to solve is when a catalog is deleted, I need to remove from the user any libraries that were contained within that catalog, but not if those libraries were also present in a different catalog that the user also has access to.

I've been stuck on this for a while now, so any help would be **GREATLY** appreciated.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: you can setup cascade deletes or just start with the tables furthest away and go from there until you delete the catalog row. If you missed anything and you have your foreign keys created correctly sql will let you know you are missing something.

Comment: Unfortunately cascading won't work in this case, as it is possible for a user to see a library because of more than one catalog. In that case, the library shouldn't be removed from the user when one of the catalogs is removed.

Comment: Remember we can't see your screen, we have no idea what your table structures are and we have no idea what you are really trying to do. Post some tables and sample data along with an explanation and you will be rewarded with some working code. Continue to keep the details hidden and be rewarded with frustration and aggravation because "nobody can help me"

Comment: Sean; I've provided the details in the question. I listed out all 6 tables, along with the parts of the structures that actually matter (in this case the relevant keys). There are 3 primary tables, and 3 linking tables, as shown.